# SQL Server cross join performance

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table that has 14,091 rows (2 columns, let's say first name, last name). I then have a calendar table that has 553 rows of just dates (first of each month). I do a cross join in order to get every combination of first name, last name, & first of month because this is my requirement. This takes just over a minute.

Is there anything I can do about this to make it faster or can a cross join never get any faster like I suspect?

People Table

```
first_name varchar2(100)
last_name varchar2(1000)
```

Dates Table

```
dt DateTime


select a.first_name, a.last_name, b.dt
from people a, dates b
```

Comment: There's no really much way to optimize a caretesian product since by definition it just multiplies all the records. There's no filtering or indexing to help here that I am aware of.

Comment: How much of that time is query time vs. I/O?

Comment: There is also no sane requirement resulting in loading nearly 8 million rows into a data table.

Comment: Takes just over a minute to do what with it? Are you sending 7 million rows over the network?

Comment: @MartinSmith Just running it via SQL Server Management Studio

Comment: Well that will take a long time to display the results. What is the goal of producing these 7.8 million rows? How are you actually planning on processing them?

Comment: @MartinSmith I filter on the results and only show a subset. However, I need all records to correctly calculate the subset since we have initial values and delta values after that and I'm converting those to actual values. So the amount I'll actually send to a web server will be much less. I guess this helps me determine that I'll have to have some process do this in the background, but it makes it hard since users can add/delete/edit delta records and would want to see the result of those instantly.

Comment: You're probably better off asking a question about the best way of achieving your end goal with more details of the problem.

Comment: What are these values and delta values you're talking about? And what about the filters? It would help a lot if you showed the entire query you're working on, since it's not possible to optimize the cross join you posted in any way, shape or form.

Comment: I'll make another post more specific to the problem. I have multiple solutions to the problem but all are proving to be slow so I thought I'd post on those first to see if there is anything I could do to speed them up. This was a long shot but thought there might be some trick with something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will be slow as it making all possible combinations. 14091 * 553. It will not going to be fast until you have either index or inner join.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah. Takes over a minute. Let's get this clear. You talk of 14091 * 553 rows - that is 7792323. Rounded that is 7.8 million rows. And loading them into a data table (which is not known for performance).

Want to see slow? Put them into a grid. THEN you see slow.

The requirements make no sense in a table. None. Absolutely none.

And no, there is no way to speed up the loading of 7.8 million rows into a data structure that is not meant to hold these amounts of data.

Comment: I'm using first/last name as an example. As this is for a private business I'm not going to exactly say what is needed but it's the same idea. A 2 column table mixed with a 1 column date table. There is a perfectly valid requirement for this.

Comment: They say "dates" table, rather than mentioning anything about datatables but I agree the chances of this really being a sane requirement are low.